# OPENCV : How to stream a video simultaneously at different resolutions

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, opencv3.0

I am trying to stream at two different resolutions at 1920x1080 and 1080x720  from a camera at the same time. But this is not happening since I am closing the first to start the second, if I do not close the first one the camera is giving out a black screen. 
So what I am trying is it possible or should I set the size of my window to match the second resolution.Here is my code.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3,1920)
cap.set(4,1080)
cap.set(5,60)

while(True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap1.set(3,1080)
cap1.set(4,720)
cap1.set(5,60)

while(True):
    ret1,frame1 = cap1.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame1',frame1)
    cv2.imwrite("frame1.jpg",frame1)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: probably your device or the driver or the openCV interface can't provide multiple capturing from the same device. Is it an option to capture the 1920x1080 stream and downscale the image manually?

Comment: First of all, do you want to capture really simultaneously, or just the second option after closing the first one? Your code is written for starting capturing at 720p only after stopping reading at 1080p